# liveagent.startChatWithWindow with userId ignore 'Custom Chat Page' and open default chat

Tags: liveagent

When liveagent chat is started by liveagent.startChatWithWindow without specifying userId - Custom Chat Page is used (ok), but when userId is specified - Custom Chat Page is ignored and default chat page is used (not ok).

so, what is wrong? i want to specify userId and use Custom Chat Page.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/live_agent_dev/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/live_agent_launching_chat_request_API_startChatWithWindow.htm

Comment: Hi Anastasia. I have noticed your question has been ignored until now (as ALL the questions I have on the Liveagent). Have you found a solution at the end?

Answer (score -1):

This is a bug that will be fixed in the Spring '16 release.

Comment: Now is this bug fixed? I always have this issue. Thanks

Comment: Keenan, any references ?