# Salesforce Chat - Direct-to-Agent

Tags: visualforce, liveagent, chat

any one knows why when using direct-to-agent using deployment api it doesn't launched the custom chat page? it always launch the standard chat window with plain design.

I'm launching it using the deployment api function.

```
liveagent.startChatWithWindow(buttonId, mywindow, agentId);
```

my button is set to launch a custom visualforce page to handle the chat but for some reason, direct-to-agent is not doing it..

it works perfectly fine for chat to any.

**Standard Chat that direct-to-agent launches**

[image]

**Custom Chat Page**

[image]

tia!

Comment: just found this 2 existing same unsolved questions...

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/77129/liveagent-startchatwithwindow-with-userid-ignore-custom-chat-page-and-open-def

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/91446/liveagent-startchatwithwindow-wrong-chat-page

Comment: anyone who bumped to this issue, the only workaround I thought of this is to create a button for each agent, the chat to any button can detect if the agent is available or not, if available, start the chat with the agent specific button (don't forget to initialize the button on page load so it startChat will work)